# Error creating oauth access token using django-oauth2-provider

Tags: django, oauth-2.0, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

When I send a HTTP POST request to create an access token for a user, with parameters `client_id`, `client_secret`, `username`, `password` etc., to my localhost which has Django (v1.7) running, I get an access token in response.

But when I do the same to Django (v1.7) deployed on Elastic Beanstalk, I get

> **TypeError at /oauth2/access_token**
>
> __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'mimetype'

I used to get this error earlier when I was using Django 1.8 but then I downgraded to Django 1.7 and this error got resolved. This all was done locally, in localhost. But when I deployed to beanstalk, I again get this error even though the version deployed there is 1.7.

Answer (score 1):

This error happen because pass mimetype to HttpResponse was removed of Django 1.7  ( https://github.com/django/django/commit/8eadbc5a03d06f5bfedfa3fad35ad0801d2ab6ff ).

I believe that some possibilities are,

- You can use another solution as django-oauth-toolkit;
- You can change line 491 at
  https://github.com/caffeinehit/django-oauth2-provider/blob/master/provider/views.py#L491
  to use content_type instead of mimetype;
- Or you can use a django-oauth2-provider fork that already resolved it developed by glassresistor user.  In this case you can:

> Install with pip

```
$ pip install https://github.com/glassresistor/django-oauth2-provider/archive/stable.zip#django-oauth2-provider
```

> or add directly in requirements.txt:

```
-e git+https://github.com/glassresistor/django-oauth2-provider.git#egg=django-oauth2-provider
```